# What are the laws governing eviction of a fired employee out from the office?

Tags: united-kingdom, dismissal

The laws on dismissing an employee in the UK are [in this link](https://www.gov.uk/dismiss-staff/dismissals-on-capability-or-conduct-grounds). What are the laws dictating how a dismissed employee must be walked out of the office? For example, is it legal to not allow him/her to collect her bag/wallet/coat etc, and instead get another employee to fetch them from their desk and hand it over to them? What laws govern the walking out process?

Comment: In England you can [use reasonable force](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2007/jun/08/yourrights.legal) to remove someone from your property if they refuse to leave. Why would you believe people have a legal right to remain at a workplace after being dismissed?

Comment: The reason is in the question: an employee has usually been granted a longstanding right to be in the office, and to keep their own belongings in certain locations of that office. If my bag, purse, wallet, reading glasses, phone, whatever, are in my desk, and I've had a very reasonable expectation of being able to use that desk as well as fetch my items at any time, then even if I were fired I don't think it would be unreasonable for me to say "I'm going to go and get my things." It's not like a movie theater can steal people's coats and purses by evicting them when they go to the bathroom.

Comment: @user99478 Some businesses will reasonably want to prevent the former worker from accessing property that doesn't belong to the former worker.

Comment: @Lag Yes, absolutely. Hence the question. Does the (ex)employee have any legal right to retrieve their belongings *now*? Can the business simply eject them and say "we'll get your personal items back to you *eventually*"? Can the employee say "I don't want anyone going through/touching my things"? Can the employee demand to be present when their items are retrieved, even if they aren't permitted to touch anything? &c &c &c. In practice I'm sure most workers who are precipitously fired are tossed out with a box of whatever security found on their desk. But what are the legal rights?